# ansible script to set gradle home?

Tags: gradle, ansible, environment-variables

How to set gradle home using ansible script. I have a directory `gradle_user_home` in RHEL. I'm trying to set gradle home to this directory with ansible script. But ansible script says no such file or directory! Below is my script.

```
- name: Set gradle environment variable
  command: export GRADLE_USER_HOME={{gradle_home}}
```

My vars file:

```
gradle_home: "/data1/deployment/gradle_user_home"
```

Comment: Because there is no command `export` and Ansible is perfectly right. Regardless of that, you won't be able to do what you think you should do, because it does not make any sense. Please learn how Unix/Linux shells work with regard to environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `export` is not a command (ie there is no `/bin/export` executable). It is a `bash` built-in. That's why you get a `no such file or directory`. You can use it in a `shell` task, not in a `command` task.

Secondly, this is not the proper way to set environment variables with Ansible.

You can set environment at the play level like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  environment:
    GRADLE_USER_HOME: "{{gradle_home}}"
```

Or at the task level like this:

```
- name: Execute gradle build
  shell: gradle build
  environment:
    GRADLE_USER_HOME: "{{gradle_home}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not export an environment variable in a single `command` task, because each `command` task is run in its own shell. After the command finishes the environment variable is lost.

You have to use the `shell` action to

1. set the environment variable and
2. run the command.

Example:

```
- name: Run the command
  shell: >-
    export GRADLE_USER_HOME={{gradle_home}}
    my_command_which_requires_gradle_user_home
```